# HTML Checkbox dynamically appended to list with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox, dhtml

I havent been using jquery, javascript and HTML to to create a list a products and the task I am attempting to do now is to be able to select multiples from a list.

So far what is working is I have a HTML  list and I can dynamically add through javascript the `<li>` required for each in the list.
The problem is, the checkboxes are not checking at all. The even stranger thing is if I click on a checkbox multiple times very fast, it will check.
Another feature I wish to add once the checkboxes are working is if a list item is clicked on, it automatically checks the checkbox related to that list. Would anyone mind helping me with these issues? Thank you and here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Progress Bar Scripts-->
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="searchProducts" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline"> <a onclick="" data-icon="back">Back</a>

             <h1>Search Products</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name">Product:</label>
                <form action="javascript:searchProducts('denim')">
                    <input type="search" name="searchboxProd" id="searchboxProd" value="denim" />
                    <!--<a href="#" data-role="button" style="width: 200px">Search</a>-->
                </form>
                <ul id="ProductsFound" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Products Found</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="prodList"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function searchProducts(prod) {
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    $('#ProductsFound').append($('<li/>').append($('<a/>', {
        //'href': '#prod',
        //'onclick': 'selectProduct(' + i + ') ',
    }).append($('<fieldset/>', {
        'data-role': 'controlgroup'
    }).append($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'checkbox',
            'id': 'checkbox-2b',
            'data-theme': 'c',
            'onclick': 'checked=true'
    })).append($('<label/>', {
        'for': 'checkbox-2b'

    }).append($('<label/>', {
        'text': '    Denim ' + i
    }))))));
}
$('#ProductsFound').listview('refresh');

}
```

some of the `<li>`'s produced (ProductsFound.innerHTML)

```
<script>\n                    
</script>\n                
<li>
<a>
<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\">
    <input id=\"checkbox-2b1\" onclick=\"checked=true\" type=\"checkbox\" data-theme=\"c\">

    <label for=\"checkbox-2b\">
        <label>    Denim 1</label>
    </label>
</fieldset>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: The only real relevant code in the _HTML_ section is `<ul id="ProductsFound" ...>...</ul>`. The more interesting _HTML_ would be a few of the generated `<li>`s.

Comment: how will i view those? apologies, im new to javascript and such

Comment: @PaulS. here is some of the produced innerHTML <script>\n                    
</script>\n                
<li>
<a>
<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\">
 <input id=\"checkbox-2b1\" onclick=\"checked=true\" type=\"checkbox\" data-theme=\"c\">

 <label for=\"checkbox-2b\">
  <label>    Denim 1</label>
 </label>
</fieldset>
</a>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

I ran it through a fiddle and I had the opposite problem to you. I can check them, but because you have

```
onclick : checked=true
```

if you did get it to check, a checkbox will never uncheck

Secondly, all the checkboxes have the same ID. Big no-no.

Comment: oops, didnt notice that id thing.

Comment: ok, changed to all unique id's now and taken checked=true thing out. Still not working

Comment: how did you manage to get that code working on jsfiddle? i tried it but nothing will come out in the list

Comment: i tried putting that code into my jsfiddle but instead of  checkboxes and labels, i got textboxes! i did copy and paste too

Comment: hard coded an li and it works fine, jquery mobile might be the problem with dynamic html